# SOAP Request Parameters dont arrive in PHP function

Tags: php, web-services, soap, parameters, wsdl

i am working on a SOAP Webservice with WSDL Support.
The WSDL file is located here: http://paygoo.com/soap/server.wsdl

I have 3 functions in my Webservice.
GetUserInfo, TransferFromWallet and TransferToWallet.

The function GetUserInfo works fine, so i designed the two other functions like this, but the other two functions TransferFromWallet and TransferToWallet dont recive the parameters from the client.

the function GetUserInfo looks like this:

```
function GetUserInfo($sessionID)
{
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
        {
            $element->balance = new SoapVar($balance, XSD_DECIMAL, '','','');
            $element->currencyCode = new SoapVar("EUR", XSD_STRING, '','','');
            $element->displayName = new SoapVar($row['username'], XSD_STRING, '','','');
            $element->languageCode = new SoapVar("DE", XSD_STRING, '','','');
            $element->UID = new SoapVar($row['ID'], XSD_STRING, '','','');
            $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("OK", XSD_STRING, '','','');
            return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
        }else
        {
            $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("UNEXPECTED_ERROR", XSD_STRING, '','','');
            return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
        }
    }else
    {
        $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("INVALID_SESSION", XSD_STRING, '','','');
        return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
    }
}
```

the functions TransferFromWallet and TransferToWallet looks like this:

```
    function TransferFromWallet($sessionID, $UID, $amount)
{
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
            if ($row2['ID'] == $UID)
            {
                if($amount > 0 and $amount <= $balance)
                {
                    $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("OK", XSD_STRING, '','','');
                    return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
                }else
                {
                    $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("BALANCE_TOO_LOW", XSD_STRING, '','','');
                    return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
                }
            }else
            {
                $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("INVALID_UID", XSD_STRING, '','','');
                return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
            }
        }else
        {
            $element->responseCode = new SoapVar("INVALID_SESSION", XSD_STRING, '','','');
            return new SoapVar($element, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'');
        }
}
```

i defined all functions and the server like this:

```
$server = new SoapServer("./soap/server.wsdl", 
array('uri' => "http://paygoo.com/server.php"));
//Funktionen zum SOAP Server hinzufügen
$server->addFunction('GetUserInfo');
$server->addFunction('TransferFromWallet');
$server->addFunction('TransferToWallet');
//Hier wird die Abfrage abgearbeitet
$server->handle();
```

my test client looks like this:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
$requesttype = $_REQUEST['soapRequest']; //Art des Requests Variable wird gesetzt.
$sessionID = $_REQUEST['sessionID']; //session_id Variable wird gesetzt.
$UID = $_REQUEST['UID']; //UserID Variable wird gesetzt
$amount = $_REQUEST['balance']; //Zu transferierendes Guthaben Varialbe wird gesetzt
//$client = new SoapClient('http://paygoo.com/soap/server.wsdl');  //{url} wie immer ersetzen

//$sessionID = 'ae3a12e662884604c069b4dfc5a13afd';
$wsdl = 'http://paygoo.com/soap/server.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
if($requesttype=="GetUserInfo")
{
    //$parms = array('sessionID' => $sessionID);
    $result = $client->GetUserInfo($sessionID);
}
if($requesttype=="TransferFromWallet"){
//$parms = array('sessionID' => $sessionID, 'UID' => $UID, 'amount' => $amount);
$result = $client->TransferFromWallet($sessionID, $UID, $amount);
}

if($requesttype=="TransferToWallet"){
    //$parms = array('sessionID' => $sessionID, 'UID' => $UID, 'amount' => $amount);
    $result = $client->TransferToWallet($sessionID, $UID, $amount);
}
?>
<h1>Result</h1>
<pre> <?php var_dump($result) ?> </pre>
```

the SOAP server don't receive the parameters sessionID, UID and amount.

EDIT:
i defined the parameters now in the `<types>` tag. like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault='qualified' targetNamespace='http://paygoo.com/soap/server.wsdl'>
        <xsd:element name='transferRequest'>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1' name='sessionID' type='xsd:string'/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1' name='UID' type='xsd:string'/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1' name='amount' type='xsd:decimal'/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name='transferResponse'>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1' name='ResponseCode' type='xsd:string'/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

if i send this request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:xmethodsWallet">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:TransferFromWallet soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <transferRequest>
      <sessionID>c230f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d</sessionID>
      <UID>975</UID>
      <amount>1</amount>
      </transferRequest>
      </urn:TransferFromWallet>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my function `TransferFromWallet` didnt recive any parameters.
if i run `__getFunctions` and `__getTypes` on Client i am getting the following response:

```
Funktionen

 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(43) "string GetUserInfo(string $userinfoRequest)"
  [1]=>
  string(69) "transferResponse TransferFromWallet(transferRequest $transferRequest)"
  [2]=>
  string(67) "transferResponse TransferToWallet(transferRequest $transferRequest)"
}

Typen

 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(75) "struct transferRequest {
 string sessionID;
 string UID;
 decimal amount;
}"
  [1]=>
  string(49) "struct transferResponse {
 string ResponseCode;
}"
}
```

could anyone tell me why i dont recive the parameters in the function?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @John Saunders... the main reason given on the link you mention in your comment is that there is no need for the extra clutter so people can see the answer easier right? Maybe the masses should consider that while cluttering what seems to be EVERY SO question with their opinions of proper questions, proper security procedures, deprecated functions, etc. though they may be valid statements, they most always NEVER have anything to do with the question. Consistency man... consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:
The SOAP Service transfers an object to my Server.
I had to read this object like this:

```
function TransferFromWallet($transferRequest)
{
        $sessionID= $transferRequest->sessionID;
        $UID = $transferRequest->UID;
        $amount = $transferRequest->amount;
                .
                .
                .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the WSDL, define your input parameters as a complexType:

```
<message name='TransferFromWalletRequest'>
    <part name="parameters">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name='sessionID' type='xsd:string'/>
                <element name='UID' type='xsd:string'/>
                <element name='amount' type='xsd:decimal'/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </part>
</message>
```

Do the same for `TransferToWallet`. Even though `GetUserInfo` only takes a single parameter, you should give it the same treatment as above because you actually haven't got a named parameter for that, it's just taking the first parameter.

Comment: UPDATE:
yesterday all worked with <complexType>. Today i tried, but there appeared the following error as SOAP response:
"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Unexpected WSDL element &lt;complexType>"
why that error appears?

Comment: you have an error in your WSDL. Seems you have `&lt` instead of `<`. Change that.

Comment: could you maybe take a look at my wsdl file? we don't know what the mistake could be... `&lt;`is not the mistake i wrote all new.

Comment: @CrAzY_130ng0 see my edit. I think you need a `<part name="parameters">` to wrap around the complexType. Do this for all services.

Comment: sorry i have one more problem. if i send 1 parameter to my server he response ok, but i have to send 3 parameters. if i send them my server response "Error cannot find parameters". do you know what the problem could be? im very new to soap. i hope its the last problem.

Comment: Can you add your code for the call to the question so I can see how you are passing the parameters.

Comment: i added the requests and responses to my question.

Comment: Ok, can you show the PHP code for when you call `TransferFromWallet` on the client?

Comment: done. all information you need should be now in the question.
btw thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm, the request looks correct because the params are wrapped in `TransferFromWallet` which is normal. In your PHP function, try changing `$balance_send` to `$amount` because that's how it's defined in the wsdl